# Retrieving Object array from the Object array list of its very first index

Tags: java

I am getting an object array inside a arraylist that is also of Object type. I know within the very first index of the object array list I have a nested object array and I have to retrieve that array. How can I do this? Right now I am iterating over complete object array list which is not good as I know I have to retrieve the object array from the very first object list element.

```
List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object[]> listObj = (List<Object[]>)query.getResultList();
for(Object[] obj: listObj){
    resultList.add(((String)obj[0]));
    resultList.add(((String)obj[1]));
}
```

Comment: [`listObj.get(0);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int))?

Comment: Are you trying to get all the elements of type as same as the type of the first element? Is this your question?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this answer because this is exactly what you want:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8882358/9016740

You can access the first element of an `ArrayList` by using the `get(index)` method as such:

```
List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object[]> listObj = (List<Object[]>)query.getResultList();
Object[] firstObjArray = listObj.get(0);
resultList.add(((String)firstObjArray[0]));
resultList.add(((String)firstObjArray[1]));
```

Comment: Your answer helped me. I tried it for hours but your answer was a quick solution. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

Object[] resultArr = listObj.get(0);

Now use resultArr to fetch values and store in resultList.

Comment: Please show the complete process as rhe op has shown